# в чем проблема при замене переменной ? js

Tags: javascript

Всегда выводит 2 почему ?

```js
var a = 1;
var b = 1 + a;

function test() {
  a = 2
  console.log(b)
  return a
}

test()

console.log(b)
```

Comment: а что должно выводиться?

Comment: @Grundy цифра 3

Comment: Тут надо понимать области видимости переменных в Javascript. Тема достаточно большая, поэтому рекомендовал бы Вам почитать статьи на эту тему.

Comment: @Lukas, области видимости тут не при чем

Comment: потому что, вы сначала посчитали значение для переменной `b`. А потом уже изменили переменную `a`

Comment: @Grundy, как я понял из вопроса, автор не понимает что он в функции выводит переменную b, которую он объявил  вне функции.

Comment: @Lukas, Не, он не понимает, что присваивание выполняется именно там где написано.

Comment: @Lukas и переменная превосходно выводится, потому что никаких проблем с областью видимости здесь нет

Comment: @andreymal, а я разве сказал что тут есть проблемы с выводом? Если у человека вопрос, почему внутри функции не поменялось значение переменной которая объявлена вне ее, то решил что он не понимает откуда она вообще выводится вот и все.

Comment: @Lukas значение переменной `a` очень даже поменялось

Comment: @andreymal да, только там выводится переменная b.

Comment: @Lukas которая нигде не изменялась, следовательно области видимости тут ни при чём

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хотя ожидаемый вами подход теоретически имеет право на существование (подобным образом ведут себя, например, формулы в ячейках Excel), большинство современных языков программирования устроены не так.

Переменная, образно говоря, просто хранит в себе кусок данных. Переменная ничего не знает про формулу, которая этот кусок данных вычисляет. Когда вы пишете `b = 1 + a`, вычисляется значение справа от знака `=` — это будет `2`, а дальше это число `2` помещается в переменную `b`. Всё! В переменной `b` лежит число `2`, и до тех пор, пока кто-нибудь не напишет `b = ...` ещё раз — эта двойка никуда не денется. Переменная `b` ничего не знает про `1 + a` — оно вычислилось один раз во время работы этой строчки, и всё. Следовательно, когда вы напишете `a = 2`, в переменной `b` так и останется лежать двойка, а тройка там ниоткуда не появится, пока вы сами не запихнёте её туда.

Вычисление нового значения — это выполнение какого-то кода. После изменения переменной `a` вам нужно как-то явно запустить код, который вычислит новое значение. Способ «в лоб» — просто повторить этот код после изменения переменной `a`:

```
function test() {
  a = 2
  b = 1 + a
  console.log(b)  // Теперь будет 3
  return a
}
```

Очевидно, что это решение не всегда удобно. Как более удобный вариант можно просто избавиться от переменной `b` и использовать вместо неё функцию — при каждом вызове функции будет каждый раз выполняться код, вычисляющий новое значение:

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    return 1 + a;
}

function test() {
  a = 2
  console.log(b())  // Будет 3
  return a
}

console.log(b())  // Будет 2
test()
console.log(b())  // Будет 3
```

Однако если вычислений много и они медленные, то постоянные перевычисления могут привести к тормозам программы. Поэтому иногда может быть разумно поместить результат работы функции во временную переменную и использовать уже её (но нужно это делать осторожно):

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    return 1 + a;
}

function test() {
  a = 2
  console.log(b())  // Будет 3
  return a
}

var old_b = b();  // Сохраняем результат вычисления в переменную
console.log(b())  // Будет 2
console.log(old_b)  // Будет тоже 2
test()
console.log(b())  // Будет 3
console.log(old_b)  // Будет 2, потому что переменную old_b никто не изменял
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблемы нет: значение переменной `b` присваивается один раз.

```
var b = 1 + a;
```

Так как дальше переменная не изменяется странно рассчитывать на разный результат вызова

```
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Можно ли сделать что бы происходила замена переменных ?

Comment: @hitt, какая итоговая цель преследуется?

Comment: 3 должно получится

Comment: @hitt если вам нужно каждый раз пересчитывать значение, то просто поместите вычисление в функцию и используйте функцию вместо переменной, например

Comment: @andreymal все бы хорошо, но в моем коде переменная b занимает 15 строк кода

Comment: @hitt и в чём проблема завернуть 15 строк кода в функцию?

Comment: @andreymal подробнее пожалуйста (js поверхностно знаю)

Comment: @hitt `function b() { return 1 + a; }` же да и всё, а дальше ставим `b()` где надо

Comment: @andreymal поставь как ответ, отмечу правильным :)